# Avoid WorkManager Worker to resume/start on device restart

Tags: android, synchronization, restart, android-workmanager

I'm planning to use WorkManager to sync some user selection to the backend. However I want to cancel the jobs when the device is off (e.g., run out of battery etc) or prevent the jobs from resumed/started when the device is back on. The reasoning is after a while the selection may not be necessary anymore and the app should not silently sync it to the server when the device is back on (user perhaps does not remember they've made such selection before).

My understanding is WorkManager by default would persist the jobs in its own db and automatically restarts them on device restart, wondering if anyone knows how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use Receiver when Device Restarts and Then Cancel unique Work Using

> WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelUniqueWork(TAG);

where TAG is the tag of your unique work item

Comment: Thanks, but I feel this is a kinda workaround and also it leaks the concern of this syncing work to the broader app. I hope there is a more standard way of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to let the work start, then check the time to determine whether it should run the rest of it.

- Send queue timestamp via input data
- Check timestamp in `doWork()` and if it exceeds, return `Result.failure()` immediately